# Spring MVC Validator in JSP, add around field

Tags: jquery, validation, jsp, model-view-controller

I have a Spring MVC jsp page. I would like to display the errors and then modify the style of all the fields that have errors on them. The field changes quite drastically, it gets an exclamation image, label changes color, field box higlighted and message displayed next to it.

This is how far I got (Let me know if you would like to see sections of the controller or validator).

```
<div class="alert alert-danger"><form:errors path="*" cssClass="error"/></div>
```

At the point where I inserted this I get a red box with the error messages, which is perfect, but now I need to update the fields.

This is a sample of two of the fields on the page that get validated (it is surrounded by a form tag):

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address:</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrTwo" value="${cardApplicationDto.cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrTwo}">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Suburb:</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrThreeSub" value="${cardApplicationDto.cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrThreeSub}">
        </div>

 </div>
```

The form control around:

```
<form:form commandName="cardApplicationDto" method="post" action="" id="MainForm">
```

I started this section in the $(document).ready(function() {

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       var showError = "${cardApplicationDto.cardAppDto.showErrors}";
       var fieldErrors = ${errors.fieldErrors};
       if (showError == "SHOW"){
            console.log("Inside if");
            var id = "";
            var groupDiv = "";
            fieldErrors.each(function (index) {

                console.log("inside for");
                id = this.key.replace(/\./g, "\\.").replace(/\[/g,"").replace(/\]/g,"").replace(/ /g,"\\ ");
                console.log(id);
                groupDiv = $("#" +id).closest("div.form-group");
                console.log(groupdiv);
                groupDiv.addClass("has-error");
                groupDiv.find('label.control-label').prepend('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-f2 color--error"></i>&nbsp;');
                groupDiv.append('<span class="help-block">${error.defaultMessage}</span>');
            });
       }



        //Some other functions here
```

I am not even sure if this is the right way to do this, but if it is on the right track...something is not working with my JQuery :(

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question has nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.